# SEO friendly dynamic php URL with .htaccess does not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having problems with creating a SEO friendly URL with the .htaccess file. So I have this current url: `www.mywebsite.com/user.php?u=username` and I want to create something like this: `www.mywebsite.com/user/username`. I've tried several methods but none of them succeeded. (mod_rewrite is activated in the apache server)
**Current code:**

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?u=$1
```

I also want to allow spaces or `%20` signs in the url. All in all how could I solve it? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ user.php?u=$1 [L]
```

for `www.mywebsite.com/user/username`

---

If you want to allow letters and numbers with special characters you can use

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ user.php?u=$1 [L]
```

I recommend manually allowing the special characters inside `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` to prevent `XSS Attacks` coming from your `$_GET Request`

Comment: It works but I lost all my style on the page. How could I fix it?

Comment: @MarkFrankli I suppose all `URLs` in the page are broken after that, Try starting everything with `/`, Check the `stylesheet` too. So any URL like this `href="user/file.php"` change it to `href="/user/file.php"`, You just need to define the root in it.